# With Apache httpd, how do I configure no caching for a given UserAgent?

Tags: apache, configuration, caching, user-agent

I have Apache HTTPD configured to add a cache header to requests for most static content:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

# Force JNLP and BSH files to expire immediately so updates are checked for
# and seen (We need this so we see changes in the dynamic content in both)
ExpiresByType application/x-java-jnlp-file "now"
ExpiresByType application/x-bsh "now"
```

How can I disable this caching for any request where the `UserAgent` contains the string JNLP?  When the request comes from the User Agent JNLP (for example "`User-Agent: JNLP/6.0 javaws/1.6.0_12 (b04) Java/1.6.0_12`") I don't want *any* `Cache-Control` or other cache-related headers on the HTTP response.

I can find configuration examples for several things based on user agent, but I cannot figure out how to configure caching depending on the user agent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ExpiresByType` directive looks like a good idea... if that's not enough, then try using `BrowserMatch`:

```
BrowserMatch JNLP ua_is_jnlp
```

This sets the environment variable `ua_is_jnlp` to some value for any request whose user agent header contains the string `JNLP` (there is also a case-insensitive variant, `BrowserMatchNoCase`). Then you can clear any caching headers with

```
Header unset Cache-Control env=ua_in_jnlp
Header unset Expires env=ua_in_jnlp
```

although if you want to disable caching entirely, you'd be better off setting

```
Header set Cache-Control no-cache env=ua_in_jnlp
Header set Expires 0 env=ua_in_jnlp
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I figured it out just before your post but then saw your post, awarded you the "correct answer" checkmark and deleted my post.